# How to send one signal push notification with large image using PHP

Tags: php, onesignal

Code sends only a title and message but icon not getting received. I am new to one signal API. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => 'my app id',
        'include_player_ids' => ['player_id'],
        'contents' => array("en" =>"test message"),
        'headings' => array("en"=>"test heading"),
        'largeIcon' => 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-512.png',
    );
    
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    //print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    //print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        'Authorization: Basic M2ZNDYtMjA4ZGM2ZmE5ZGFj'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                                           
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: @Akintunde007 that one was chrome notification i wanna send to mobile device

Comment: remove your auth details!

Comment: @Marinus its not my full auth .

Answer (score 2):

You just simply add:
"chrome_web_image" => "image url";

```
$fields = array(
            'app_id' => 'my app id',
            'include_player_ids' => ['player_id'],
            'contents' => array("en" =>"test message"),
            'headings' => array("en"=>"test heading"),
            'chrome_web_image' => 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-512.png',
            );
```

To further reading please go to: [doc appearance of onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-appearance)

Result:
[image: image result]

Answer (score 0):

They key for the icon should be `large_icon` not `largeIcon`

Check [the API for more details](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ios_attachments` parameter and it must be in array.

This is how I did it:

```
$iCon = array(  
    "ios_attachments" => 'https://Your.Image.png'
);
 
$fields = array(     
    // OneSignal - Personal ID
    'app_id' => "Your_OneSignal_ID",
    'included_segments' => array('All'),'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        
    // Submitting Title && Message && iCon
    'headings' => $headings,
    'contents' => $content,
    'ios_attachments' => $iCon,
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $fields = array(
        'app_id' => $app_id,
        'headings' => array("en"=>$data['title']),
        'contents' => ["en" => $data['description']] ,
        'big_picture' => $data['file'],
        'large_icon' => $data['file'],
        'url' =>  $data['launch_url']
    );
```

Comment: Would be good if you could provide an explanation with your answer?

Comment: array key must be 'large_icon'  .  not largeIcon    and   Big Picture must be big_picture , not bigPicture